# Change the character encode in PostgreSQL C language function

Tags: c, postgresql, utf-8, multibyte

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 64bit version on windows server.
The character encoding of the database is set to UTF8.

I'd like to create a function that manipulates multibyte strings.
(e.g. cleansing, replace etc.)

I copied C language logic for manipulating characters from a other system,
The logic assumes that the character code is sjis.

I do not want to change C language logic, so I want to convert from UTF8 to sjis in C language function of Postgresql.
Like the convert_to function. (However, since the convert_to function returns bytea type, I want to obtain it with TEXT type.)

Please tell me how to convert from UTF 8 to sjis in C language.

Create Function Script:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CLEANSING_STRING(character varying)
RETURNS character varying AS
'$libdir/MyFunc/CLEANSING_STRING.dll', 'CLEANSING_STRING'
LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT;
```

C Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <postgres.h>
#include <port.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <builtins.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

extern PGDLLEXPORT Datum CLEANSING_STRING(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(CLEANSING_STRING);
Datum CLEANSING_STRING(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    // Get Arg
    text *arg1 = (text *)PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);

    // Text to Char[]
    char *arg;
    arg = text_to_cstring(arg1);

    // UTF8 to Sjis
    //Char *sjisChar[] = foo(arg);  // something like that..

    // Copied from other system.(Assumes that the character code is sjis.)
    cleansingString(sjisChar);
    replaceStrimg(sjisChar);

    // Sjis to UTF8
    //arg = bar(sjisChar);  // something like that..

    //Char[] to Text and Return
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(arg));
}
```

Comment: See the functions `any_to_server` and `server_to_any` in `src/backend/utils/mb/mbutils.c`, and the comments at the top of `mbutils.c`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I do not understand how to specify the third argument encoding.
Is there a list of encoding somewhere?

Is the usage correct?
Char *sjisChar[] = server_to_any(arg, strlen(arg), /* sjis encoding number */  );

Comment: @CraigRinger  I forgot to give a mention.

Comment: sorry, `pg_server_to_any` and `pg_any_to_server`. And for the encoding name, see the `pg_enc2name_tbl` in `src/backend/utils/mb/encnames.c` and the `pg_char_to_encoding` function

Comment: @CraigRinger A program as expected was made!
Thank you very much.

The completed source will be described later as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeeded in the way I was taught by question comments.

```c
#include <mb/pg_wchar.h> //Add to include.

...

Datum CLEANSING_STRING(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    // Get Arg
    text *arg1 = (text *)PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);

    // Text to Char[]
    char *arg;
    arg = text_to_cstring(arg1);

    // UTF8 to Sjis
    Char *sjisChar[] = pg_server_to_any(arg, strlen(arg), PG_SJIS);

    // Copied from other system.(Assumes that the character code is sjis.)
    cleansingString(sjisChar);
    replaceStrimg(sjisChar);

    // Sjis to UTF8
    arg =  pg_any_to_server(sjisChar, strlen(sjisChar), PG_SJIS); //It converts from SJIS to server (UTF 8), the third argument sets the encoding of the conversion source.

    //Char[] to Text and Return
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(arg));
}
```